# Can a page to be reloaded with New HTML using Javascript

Tags: javascript

if I have a simple "hello world" page and I want to have a reload javascript function with new HTML tag in it that says "good bye everyone" and its under same url , can I have it?

I am adding this as it was confusing.

I need to page to be reloaded with New HTML tags. I need to be able to render a page as PDF in salesforce. I am making the page on the fly so I cant use local storage or anything since render:PDF tag wont be reading any javascript. So I need to be able to create my page in javascript and then some how get all the HTML content in that page and add the render pdf tag to the beginning of the HTML page and reload the page so it retuns a PDF back to me

Comment: What do you mean by "reload"? You can manipulate any part of the page.

Comment: Reloading or refreshing a page pulls data from the server or opens a file directly. So either you need to tell the server to give you a different file or you're approaching the problem from the wrong angle. You probably just want to modify the current page without reloading.

Comment: This question is really really basic, I would recommend spending at least 5 minutes searching the web before posting a question here.

Comment: @Mihailo Its not that basic. What is happening is that I need to render a page as PDF and I am not saving it anywhere. This is for Salesforce. Javascript doesnt work if you run apex page. it has to be simple HTML. So I am trying to create my page with Javascript and some how add the render pdf tag to the page and reload the page with the new html so I can get the pdf

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jxm1nzoe/

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself". Also, explain your entire problem in the question itself, not in comments.

Comment: @Metawaa Ah so the actual core of the problem you have is something you decided is not worth mentioning. _"and I am not saying it anywhere"_ :D

Comment: @Mihailo I know I thought if I say salesforce people would banned this question from here but I updated the question

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan sorry, i updated the question.

Comment: You need server-side code

Answer (score 0):

You can, but you'll have to do some javascript manipulation after the page loads. You can use HTML5 localstorage to hold the new tag(s) you want the page to include when it loads, and then use javascript to set them in the pageload event.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with no problems and reload via `.innerHTML`:

```
document.getElementById('yourID').innerHTML = 'good bye everyone';
```

It will change the inner text of your html element. And it's much easier, than setting up a server for this